# Navigation without local costmap?

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using rtabmap to generate the global cost map. I understand that local cost maps are in the Odom frame instead of map and that it's for short term path planning.
The local cost map takes the global map and sensor reading to create the new map.

But what I'm confused about is why I couldn't just use the global cost map as is? It already takes into account the sensors plus the rgdb camera. Is it because the global mapper can't run at high frequency?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351194/navigation-without-local-costmap?/) by [mugetsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1134/mugetsu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2020-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my opinion, the global cost map is used for static objects such as the wall, tables, etc; While the local cost map is used for navigating robot in a limited region depending on your robot. In this region, robot can avoid the moving obstacles when planning the path.

---

Originally posted by [tungngo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33618/tungngo/) with karma: 46 on 2020-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0